# Definition Query to exclude certain values and return remaining values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, sql, definition-query

I have been trying to create a Definition query to symbolize a set of water features. I cannot edit the .shp file and I want to exclude a multiple values. I have tried using `NOT` but have had no luck.

This is what works for one value:

```
NOT "OGF_ID" = 214620160
```

I don't know how to add more values to exclude.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12):

The `IN` operator is what you're looking for. Use a comma-separated list in parentheses, like so:

```
"OGF_ID" NOT IN (214620160, 214620161, 214620162)
```

Comment: I noticed differences between using "not in" "is not" and "<>" when trying to exclude certain field values.  Anyone have some advice on when to use which, as I am not having success with any combination.  Sometimes all features disappear, sometimes subsets which don't apply to the DQ, overall it seems very inconsistent.

Comment: @user25644 if you post a separate question, a lot more people will see it and be able to help you. In general, "not in" is used for a list of possible values surrounded by parentheses, while "<>" (i.e. "not equal to") is used to compare against a single value.